# Finding the average position of an element within a list of sorted dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a large list of dataframes. Each of them contains the same number and group of elements. They are just sorted in a different way like so.

df1

ID | Score

x | 1.59

y | 1.38

z | 1.2

df2

ID | Score

y | 1.32

x | 1.23

z | 1.08

What I want to do is analyse how the position of the each element changes from dataframe to dataframe.

To do that I first need to extract the positions of the elements in each dataframe.

I envision an output like this

ID | Position in df1 | Position in df2 | etc.

x  | 1 | 2 | etc.

y | 2 | 1 | etc.

z | 3 | 3 | etc.

So what I want is the row number of each specific element in all the dataframes.
Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please share a small reproducible example - perhaps a list of 2 data frames with 3 elements each. Either share code to simulate fake data, or use `dput()` to share an object from your R session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# sample data
my_list <- list(
  df1 = data.frame(ID = c("x", "y", "z"), Score = c(1,2,3)),
  df2 = data.frame(ID = c("y", "x", "z"), Score = c(4,5,6))
)

# for a df, return data.frame with ID and column with element name giving position

row_positions <- function(data, df) { 
  data[[df]] <- 1:nrow(data)
  data[,c("ID", df)]
}

# merge across row_position output for each element

Reduce(
  merge,
  mapply(
    FUN = row_position,
    data = my_list,
    df = names(my_list),
    SIMPLIFY = FALSE
  )
)

  ID df1 df2
1  x   1   2
2  y   2   1
3  z   3   3
```

`mapply` is used because applied functions can't normally access the names of elements that they are referencing.

If you know that all your `data.frame` objects contain the same element counts and IDs, just in different orders, you can use simpler logic:

```
sapply(
  my_list,
  FUN = function(data) { 
    x <- 1:nrow(data)
    names(x) <- data$ID
    x[order(names(x))]
  }
)

  df1 df2
x   1   2
y   2   1
z   3   3
```

However, this won't work as expected if the above conditions don't hold. Note that IDs get encoded as row names using the second approach.